# TSQL Populate Boolean values in Table A based on whether specific records exist in Table B

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables:

```
| ID | HasA | HasB | HasC | Foo | Bar |
|----|------|------|------|-----|-----|
| 12 |      |      |      |  X  |  Y  |
| 43 |      |      |      |  Y  |  X  |


| ID | Type |
|----|------|
| 12 |  A   |
| 43 |  B   |
| 12 |  C   |
| 43 |  A   |
```

I want to populate the results into Table A so that it looks like:

```
| ID | HasA | HasB | HasC | Foo | Bar |
|----|------|------|------|-----|-----|
| 12 | true |      | true |  X  |  Y  |
| 43 | true | true |      |  Y  |  X  |
```

How?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it up into two parts:

First, figure out the "HasX" using an CASE WHEN.  This is the inner subqueryA select statement.

Second, join it to the FooBar table using inner join then do a sum on the "HasX" columns to consolidate them, then use the CASE When to return values of true/false. This is the outer returning select statement.

```
SELECT subqueryA.ID
, CASE WHEN sum(subqueryA.HasA) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as HasA 
, CASE WHEN sum(subqueryA.HasB) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as HasB 
, CASE WHEN sum(subqueryA.HasC) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as HasC 
, foobar.foo
, foobar.bar
FROM
[dbo].[ABC_FooBar] foobar LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT a.ID as ID
, CASE ABCType WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HasA
, CASE ABCType WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HasB
, CASE ABCType WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HasC
FROM  [dbo].[ABC] a 
) subqueryA  on foobar.ID = subqueryA.ID
GROUP BY subqueryA.ID, foobar.foo, foobar.bar
```